# Provider is not expected in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When I tried for "terraform plan" or "terraform apply", I got the following error:

[image]

The code that I am using to launch infrastructure below:

```
provider = "aws" {
region = "us-east-2a"
}
resource "aws_instance" "my_instance"
{
   ami = "ami-0d542ef84ec55d71c"
   instance_type = "t2.micro"
   tags{
    Name="terraform"
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `=` between `provider` and `"aws"`.

Answer (score 1):

When specifying a provider the syntax is `provider "<name>" { <attributes> }` (see https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html for the specific AWS provider syntax).

In your example you have `provider = "<name>"`, but the equals sign should not be there. Instead, use this:

```
provider "aws" {
   region = "us-east-2a"
}

resource "aws_instance" "my_instance"
{
   ami = "ami-0d542ef84ec55d71c"
   instance_type = "t2.micro"
   tags {
      name="terraform"
   }
}
```